# Как получить полную информацию о типе свойства класса TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Имеется набор классов.

```
class ClassA {
  id=0;
  name='Name1';
}

class ClassB {
  id=0;
  title='Title1';
}

class Container<T> {
  array: Array<T>=[];
}

class MyClass {
  myContainerA: Container<ClassA>;
  myContainerB: Container<ClassB>;
}
```

Могу ли я получить полную информацию о типе свойства myContainerA класса MyClass? Т.е. классы какого типа содержатся в контейнере?

Comment: В смысле каким-то образом получить `ClassA` ?

Comment: Ну хотя бы 'ClassA'

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QILQN4FgBQ1oEsAmAvAAwDcm2AdmALYCmBA5AHI20CMDZGAvppqJBjxBAIVTlchUhIAuOGSHoMAKvMUcuvDPwRCA9hRlgcFWgCcAPMoB84rNDBmzYAJ4AuaIieur1ggG0AXU0+DAEoaABZF2EI9HtqGIMjE3NED1hk41NLWIhEay5sRMzDbPMRDKzU3N0RQswtTBkXAAdaaGBqnLzoAiiY3WhaAA8ZWgo8GBRoEu60qrKaixMAM3NoAA1bbmgAfi3oD1MAN3MSIA

Comment: Вы не могли бы добавить небольшой комментарий? У меня изначально есть json с бэка, я хотел бы, заглянув в экземпляр класса, в свойство myContainerA, узнать название класса в контейнере, заполнить экземплярами этого класса с помощью фабрики, на основе json данных. Не очень понял, как это сделать

Comment: Попробуйте описать то что вы хотите в вопросе, а не в комментариях.
И, насколько я понял, вы хотите получить что-то в рантайме. Но TS не работает в рантайме.

Comment: Да, это нужно именно в рантайме, значит без вариантов?

Comment: *У меня изначально есть json с бэка, я хотел бы, заглянув в экземпляр класса* - А как вы этот json преобразуете в экземпляры класса?

Comment: person:[{id:1,name:'вася'}]; class Person {id:number,name:string}. const person=factory.instance('person') as Person; пробегусь по свойствам person, достану значения с json-а. Так не пойдет?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, это почти правда. (https://www.google.com/?q=typescript%20reflect%20metadata)

Comment: @progervova, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof "Оператор instanceof проверяет, принадлежит ли объект к определённому классу"